# Consider charset while sorting with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I am getting odd results when sorting data through mongoose methods.
We have following data:

```
[
    { firstName: 'Andy' },
    { firstName: 'Łukasz' },
    { firstName: 'Jack' },
    { firstName: 'Zygmunt' },
]
```

when sorted using `asc` the results are:

```
[
    { firstName: 'Andy' },
    { firstName: 'Jack' },
    { firstName: 'Zygmunt' },
    { firstName: 'Łukasz' },
]
```

when sorted using `desc` the results are:

```
[
    { firstName: 'Łukasz' },
    { firstName: 'Zygmunt' },
    { firstName: 'Jack' },
    { firstName: 'Andy' },
]
```

execution code:

```
const users = await User.find({})
  .sort({
    firstName: 'asc',
  })
  .catch((err) => next(err));
```

schema code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
    ...
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    ...
});

schema.set("toJSON", { virtuals: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", schema);
```

mongoose connection settings:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect(config.connectionString, {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

module.exports = {
    User: require("../models/user"),
};
```

What i would expect from sorting is if we apply `asc` the results should be:

```
[
    { firstName: 'Andy' },
    { firstName: 'Jack' },
    { firstName: 'Łukasz' },
    { firstName: 'Zygmunt' },
]
```

What can be done to have it working like expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can set sort order with [Collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#collation):

```
db.users.find({}, { _id: 0 }).collation({ locale: "pl" }).sort({ firstName: 1 })

{ "firstName" : "Andy" }
{ "firstName" : "Jack" }
{ "firstName" : "Łukasz" }
{ "firstName" : "Zygmunt" }
```

Comment: what if you have special letters from various languages, because this method implies that you only can have customers from one locale to have sorting working correctly

Comment: The sort operation applies on one data set, you cannot sort a data set by different conditions. How would you expect it to work?